# Store Form data to mysql as JSON in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I want to know how to store my form input as a JSON format into mysql database.

Basically I want to know the complete flow from Blade template to database to store the JSON.

Sample Form:

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="action_page.php">

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" style="height:300px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
</div>
```

Sample JSON that I want to store in the database

```
{ "firstname":"John", "lastname":"Immanuel",  "subject":"This is a test msg" }
```

Comment: please explain more. do want store  "{ "name" : "john" }" into the table ? instead just "john" ??

Comment: Please confirm if you want to fetch and show as json format or store inside your table as json format..

Comment: I edited my question with sample form and sample JSON format. I want to store the data in that JSON format when ever the form is submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `controller` method, use following code:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function store(){
     //Get the request data
     $input = Request::all(); 

     //Store into your table using Laravel model you've created
     $record = Model::create(["your_field_name" => json_encode($input)]); 

     return $record; 
}
```

Please make sure, the `datatype` of field in which you want to store the json should be `varchar` or `text`.

Comment: Even `json` field type would be better for searching within.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a controller and add code in your router to initialize the route

Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $variable = DB::table('table_name')->insert([
            ['firstname' => $request->firstname, 'lastname' => $request->lastname, 'subject' => $request->subject]
     ]);
     return $variable;
}
```

Router: (add code in web.php)

```
Route::post('/add', 'YourController@store');
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
<form action="/add" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" style="height:300px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
</div>
```